# efficient way to convert str to integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

`Index([u'Date', u'Time', u'Hi Temperature', u'Low Temperature', u'HIT?',
       u'LOT?', u'Date+Time'],
      dtype='object')`

I created the columns 'HIT?', 'LOT?' and 'Date+Time'

I am trying to create a list of `'Date+Time'` in which a certain condition is verified, e.g.:

```
data2['HIT?'] is 'TRUE' OR data2['LOT?'] = 'TRUE'.
```

I run the script

```
Hi_Low = []
for i in data2['Date+Time']:
    if (data2[data2['Date+Time']==map(str,i)['HIT?']] == True) or (data2[data2['Date+Time']==map(str,i)]['LOT?']== True):
        Hi_Low.append(i)
    else:
        pass
```

but got the error:

> `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

I thought that the function `map` would convert the indices, but is not doing it, anybody can give me hand with this?? or any other way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc` for filtering only column `Date+Time`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'HIT?':[True, False, True, False],
                   'LOT?':[True, True, False, False],
                   'Date+Time':pd.date_range('2017-01-01 13:49:02', periods=4),
                   'Hi Temperature':[10,40,50,60],
                   'Low Temperature':[2,5,7,8]})
print (df)
  Date+Time   HIT?  Hi Temperature   LOT?  Low Temperature
0 2017-01-01   True              10   True                2
1 2017-01-02  False              40   True                5
2 2017-01-03   True              50  False                7
3 2017-01-04  False              60  False                8

Hi_Low = df.loc[df['HIT?'] | df['LOT?'], 'Date+Time'].tolist() 
print (Hi_Low)
[Timestamp('2017-01-01 13:49:02'), 
 Timestamp('2017-01-02 13:49:02'), 
 Timestamp('2017-01-03 13:49:02')]

Hi_Low = df.loc[df['HIT?'] | df['LOT?'], 'Date+Time'].astype(str).tolist() 
print (Hi_Low)
['2017-01-01 13:49:02', '2017-01-02 13:49:02', '2017-01-03 13:49:02']
```

It is same as:

```
Hi_Low = df.loc[(df['HIT?'] == True) | 
                (df['LOT?'] == True), 'Date+Time'].astype(str).tolist() 
print (Hi_Low)
['2017-01-01 13:49:02', '2017-01-02 13:49:02', '2017-01-03 13:49:02']
```

Also is possible use conditions with chaining by `|` (`or`),  `&` (`and`) or `~` (`not`):

```
Hi_Low = df.loc[(df['Hi Temperature'] > 45) | 
                (df['Low Temperature'] < 5), 'Date+Time'].astype(str).tolist() 
print (Hi_Low)
['2017-01-01 13:49:02', '2017-01-03 13:49:02', '2017-01-04 13:49:02']
```